# Какой браузерный движок для отображения кода веб страниц используется в клиенте Steam?

Tags: веб-программирование, html

Какой браузерный движок для отображения кода веб страниц используется в клиенте Steam?

Comment: webkit webkit

Answer (score 1):

**На будущее:** можно открыть любую игру, нажать shift+tab и зайти на любой сайт, предоставляющий информацию о браузере пользователя.

```
USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; Valve Steam GameOverlay/1391728617; ) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19
```

---

```
Valve Steam Game Overlay on Windows 7
IS JAVASCRIPT ENABLED?  Yes
ARE COOKIES ENABLED?    Yes
IS FLASH INSTALLED?     Flash 12.0 is installed
IS JAVA INSTALLED?      Java 7 (u51) is installed

Based on Google Chrome 18, possibly running on Windows Server 2008 R2

Your browser announces that it has these extra addons installed.
Microsoft Silverlight v5.1
Ad Blocker
```